# Using pdfcreator to convert tiff files

Tags: c#, pdf, tiff, image-conversion

I am using pdfcreator com sdk to convert files to pdf. Most of the time its htmls or images, so i use the printURL method, but if the file is tiff pdfcreator wont create the file as pdf.
When i use printFile its open a printDialog which of course its bad because its a background process. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) instead. It does a fantastic job of converting between many image formats, including TIFF and PDF. Use one of the [C# interfaces](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#dot-net).

Comment: is it  stable for commercials purposes?

Comment: @Guy It's top-quality. I've never heard anyone say bad things about it's results.

Comment: is it com or stand alone dll i could not understand from the site ?

Comment: @Guy I haven't used the C# library, so you'll have to check to see if it suites your requirements in that regard. But if it does, I couldn't recommend it more.